# How does Taal's Twinned Arrow work?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

[image: screenshot of Taal's Twinned Arrow description]

The Chaos Wastes game mode boon, "Taal's Twinned Arrow" is described:

> Ranged attacks now fire one additional projectile.

How does this work with weapons and career skills / ults where this description is not quite straightforward, like ranged attacks that don't have projectiles or have multiple projectiles per shot? For example:

- [Sienna's Beam Staff](https://vermintide2.fandom.com/wiki/Sienna%27s_Beam_Staff) - How are its beam, blast, and burst attacks affected?
- Sienna's Conflagration Staff - I noticed that it works as described with the primary fireball attack but I'm not sure how it affects the secondary area of effect attack.
- Sienna's Coruscation Staff - How are the shotgun blast-like primary attack and the secondary area of effect attack affected?
- Flamethrower-type weapons: Sienna's Flamestorm Staff and Bardin's Drakegun - How are the flames affected since they're not exactly "projectiles"?
- Sienna's staves in general: Does it also generate overcharge for the additional projectile fired?
- Shotgun-type weapons: Bardin's Grudge-Raker and Kruber's Blunderbuss - one extra pellet or double the total pellets per shot?
- Are the projectiles of ranged attack career skills / ults (e.g., Waystalker, Bounty Hunter, Pyromancer, Outcast Engineer) affected? How are they and their variations as modified by talents affected?
- [Saltzpyre's Rapier](https://vermintide2.fandom.com/wiki/Saltzpyre%27s_Rapier) special attack (pistol shot). It is not exactly classified as a ranged weapon in the game, so I'm not sure if it's also affected.

Comment: I've played a bit of Sienna in Chaos Wastes, and although my experience isn't lengthy in any extreme, I've never got Taal's Twinned Arrow for her. I typically see it on the other 4.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The first time I got Taal's Twinned Arrow, it's when I was playing Battle Wizard Sienna with Conflagration Staff.

Answer (score 1):

As of the June 2022 [Be’lakor update (Patch 4.7)](https://steamcommunity.com/games/552500/announcements/detail/3356884419716213928), Fatshark changed the Taal's Twinned Arrow from being a boon to be a ranged weapon trait instead, and restricted which weapons can have it. Ranged weapons that don't have projectiles and shotgun-type weapons are restricted from having the trait. Sienna has no access to it on any of her weapons. It should now work exactly as described on all weapons that can have it.

Only the following ranged weapons can have the Taal's Twinned Arrow weapon trait:

| Kruber | Bardin | Kerillian | Saltzpyre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Handgun | Crossbow | Briar Javelin | Brace of Pistols |
| Longbow | Drakefire Pistols | Hagbane Shortbow | Crossbow |
| Repeater Handgun | Handgun | Longbow | Repeater Pistol |
|  | Masterwork Pistol | Moonfire Bow | Volley Crossbow |
|  | Throwing Axes | Swiftbow |  |
|  | Trollhammer Torpedo | Volley Crossbow |  |

> Are the projectiles of ranged attack career skills / ults [...] affected?

Ults aren't affected by the Taal's Twinned Arrow weapon trait.

> Saltzpyre's Rapier special attack (pistol shot). [...] I'm not sure if it's also affected.

It is not affected since the Rapier is restricted from having Taal's Twinned Arrow.